# Redefinition C++ Issue, Multiple Header

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, header

I now working on project with alot of classes and sometimes i need to include like :

CSConnection.h in Player.h and Player.h in CSConnection.h, and now there my compiler got conflicts like Class name was not defined.

Headers had guard, where is problem ?

Comment: Shorten the headers and edit your question, posting them with versions that reproduce the problem. And I'm going to warn you right now that if one of these doesn't *exclusively* use the other's definitions as pointers or references to incomplete types via forward decls, you're probably doing it *wrong*.

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependencies are just bad design. If you feel the urge to have a child/owned object "know about" its parent/owner, you should pass the child a std::function instead of a full reference to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration
or Perhaps the use of a guard 'i.e. #ifdef ...' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: He uses include guards, but they are useless for cyclic inclusion

Answer (score -1):

Include guards prevent a file from being included multiple times within the same file, **but can not help you with cyclic includes**. What you probably want is forward declaration, but that depends on what's in your include files.